# Selenium 2 Web driver (Email verification)

Tags: selenium

I need to verify the email that is triggered from my application to gmail, yahoo, etc. I have done all the functional test using selenium 2 web driver till the email is triggered to gmail or yahoo. I need to verify a link in the email triggered is redirecting to my application again when I click it. Is there a way to do this in Selenium 2?

Answer (score 1):

Without providing any sort of shortcut to access the link you need to use Selenium to log in to the email address, find the email, and extract the link.

While that is feasible, it is usually not recommended since Gmail, Yahoo, or whatever service you use could change and break your test.

A better way to do it (in my opinion) is to check the email *without Selenium* (directly connect to the SMTP server for example). This way what your tests are checking is the link and not whether the login process for Gmail still works.